# Microsoft Graph API - What is the page size for every delta query on users and groups?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What is the page size for every delta query?

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_users
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_groups

My understanding is the $top doesn't work with delta query on users and groups. So we cannot set a custom page size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: For delta queries page size is not fixed/guaranteed. There's `Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=X` parameter but it doesn't work for all queries.

---

If you try to reproduce this situation in Graph Explorer using the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView/delta?startDateTime=2010-01-01 00:00:00&endDateTime=2020-01-01 00:00:00&$top=5
```

It'll give you the following error:

> The '$top' parameter is not supported with change tracking over the 'CalendarView' resource as page size cannot be guaranteed.  Express page size preferences using the Prefer: odata.maxpagesize= header instead.

As stated in this error page size is not guaranteed. However, by adding additional header

```
Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=10
```

you will be able to see that only 10 results are returned.

One remark - this param is not supported for some of the resources (also for the ones you asked about - user and group).

To see if the delta query for the other resource is supported, go to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#supported-resources), choose the API and go to *Request headers* paragraph in its documentation. If you find header with `odata.maxpagesize={x}. Optional.` in the description - it's supported.

As for today (July '18) the following APIs support `odata.maxpagesize` param: event, mailFolder, message, contactFolder, contact and the following **don't** support it: group, user, driveItem, plannerUser.

Feel free to play with [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) as it might be very helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: The following two queries give the same result:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$top=2

$top is basically ignored, I don't get an error like the calendarView/delta query.

Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=10 is not honored either.

Comment: You're right, I must have missed it - this parameter is not supported for user and groups. I'll add it to my answer later. So the conclusion will be that it works but only for some types of queries.

Comment: @SharvariKapadia, updated my answer. If you consider the answer as correct and detailed enough, feel free to mark it as accepted. Therefore people who will browse later will see that it is helpful.

Comment: for Contacts fetching, as of December 2021, `/contacts/` works with $top, while `/contacts/delta/` works with `Prefer: odata.maxpagesize=X`

Comment: Just wanted to update this. The new URL for the delta API overview is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview